# How can I transform float coordinates (rectified pixels) into int pixels in order to see a rectified image?

Tags: python

I have an array of the original pixels, then i got the new coordinates, but they are represented as floats. My problem is not representation because I can plot them in a voxel grid (they are timestamped), my problem is how transform those floats into pixel coordinates (ints) so I can use them as an input for another algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the values are floats and you need to convert to integers.

You can use:

```
np.int_(your_array)
```

Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_

If you need to make scattered points into pixel locations you could use something like 2d histogram.
Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html